# How to create my own Authorize attribute for MVC API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, authorize

I want to create a Web API MVC.
This API will authorize TOKEN JWT, and I want to create my own Authorize attribute like CanRead, CanModify, CanWrite.
Three attributes just inherit Attribute class (no AuthorizeAttribute), is it ok ?

My application have complicates role and permission so I want to customize all about authorization and authentication.
I want to manage the permission dynamic

So how can I do it ?

Will I access database from attributes (CanRead or CanModify) to check permission

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom AuthorizeAttribute instead.  an example below.

```
public class KeyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute  
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        string key = httpContext.Request["X-Key"];
        return ApiValidatorService.IsValid(key);
    }
}

public static class ApiValidatorService
{
    public static bool IsValid(string key)
    {
        int keyvalue;

        if (int.TryParse(key, out keyvalue))
        {
            return keyvalue % 2137 == 7;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Taken [from Jon Galloway's blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-authentication-customizing-authentication-and-authorization-the-right-way).  I don't know specifically how you are authorizing, but if you create a class with:

```
public bool CanRead { get; set; }
public bool CanWrite { get; set; }
public bool CanModify { get; set; }
```

And then within the AuthorizeCore method, determine based on the setting if the user has the right permission.